# How can I get final URL of HTTPResponse after redirect

Tags: android, http-post, httpresponse

I need to get the URL of the final page of the HTTPResponse after redirects. I am getting the URL of the redirect page when I try to retrieve it. I am being redirected using a javascript function on the page. Thanks.